# How do i LivePreview in VSC through the browser

Tags: javascript, html, vscode-extensions

I know that there is an extension to this, but this extension open it in VSC, and when i try to open this on the web it isnt LivePreviwed. What should i do?
Thanks

I tried to install the extension but it isnt live previewing

Comment: you need to save file first to see the preview of your website

Answer (score 1):

You can actually edit the `preview` target in the [Live Preview](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.live-server) extension settings.

1. Start the server.
2. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>.
3. Then write *Live Preview: Show Preview (External Browser)*, and choose it.

> [image: live preview settings]

Or you can try a different extension like the [Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) extension.

> Launch a local development server with a live reload feature for static & dynamic pages.
>
> [image: live server preview]

Answer (score 1):

Well, I like to have it through the node live-preview package instead of an extension.
You may achieve it in the following way::

1. 1st install [Node](https://nodejs.org/en).
2. Check you've installed node by running `node -v` in the terminal.
3. Then install the package by `npm install live-server -g`
4. Then run the live-server by running `live-server` command in your terminal.

On the 3rd point `npm` is a package manager maintained by npm and `-g` is for global installation.